# Symfony2 validation - override checkMX constraint in TEST environment

Tags: php, validation, symfony, dns, symfony-forms

I have a Symfony form with validation set up (using definitions in validations.yml file). In this form is an email field, to which I have added the **checkMX** validator constraint. This works fine under normal usage. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Email.html#checkmx

However, when running my test suite, with no internet connection, this stalls the test as the validator tries to look up the DNS of the email address domain, and it cannot look up the DNS and has to wait for the timeout. In any case requiring a remote lookup during testing is not ideal.

Is there a way to remove this constraint from the validation but only when the **TEST** environment is run? Presumably I just need to override the constraint but I don't know how to do this per-environment.

Thanks

Comment: depend on which version of the framework you use, you can take a look at [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#strict-email)

Answer (score 0):

You can get your environment from the controller and pass it to your form:

```
$env = $this->container->get( 'kernel' )->getEnvironment();
$oForm = $this->createForm(new Form($env));
```

Then before your BuildForm:

```
 public function __construct($env)
{
    $this->sEnv  = $env;
}
```

And then you do your test.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to do this globally not on a per-form basis.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been fixed since Symfony 3.1

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/phpunit_bridge.html#dns-sensitive-tests